# Display featured image of post type category

Tags: php, wp-query

I inherited a website that had a significant number of customized PHP files. I have removed many since, however, this is one of the few that still seemed relevant. The code below displays 1 image at random from a particular post type (gallery) in the website footer.

There was only one post type category prior to me working on the website. Now I have added more gallery categories, but the footer is displaying images from all categories. How can I modify this to show a particular category from the gallery post type?

```
<?php query_posts('orderby=rand&showposts=1&post_type=gallery'); 
                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
                                <script>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        $voice = '<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), "medium" ); echo $image[0]; ?>';
                        jQuery('.footer-voice').attr('src', $voice);
                    });
                </script>
                            
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate answer to your question is that you can just add a category ID to the `query_posts()` call, e.g.:

```
query_posts('orderby=rand&showposts=1&post_type=gallery&cat=10');
```

Slightly longer answer is that it's not a good idea to use `query_posts` in themes and plugins. More info in the docs here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

You might want to take the opportunity to change the code to use `get_posts` or `WP_Query`, you just need to put the arguments in an array instead of a query string.

Comment: I thought something simple like that would fix it, but it did not.

Found this code that seemed to do similarly, but it also doesn't work. Any idea why?:

`<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_type' => 'gallery', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'category_name' => 'testimonials' ) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
<div class="feature boxed testimonials">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>`

Sorry for the ugly code - I cannot figure out how to get SE to format that for me.

Comment: @NinjaValerie It's hard to review that code, but there's no reason that a valid WP_Query wouldn't work, so it's worth double checking the arguments are valid, with no typos etc. (look in the WP Query documentation which is long but lists everything), and if it seems right but the results are definitely wrong it is possible you have a bad plugin that can accidentally mess with the results. You could also try opening a new question with the WP Query you're using and your setup and what's going wrong as other people might have suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's a custom taxonomy registered for your custom post type. In this case you need to use the `tax_query` parameter for `WP_Query` to get posts from your custom taxonomy with a certain term slug.

Here's an example code for getting custom post type post with a custom term. First there's a helper function, which you can put in your `functions.php` file. The lines below it demonstrates how to use the function. You need to update the taxonomy name to match the actual one to make the query work.

The `category_name` parameter is related to the *Category* taxonomy, which is associated with the *Post* post type. If your gallery post type also uses the default categories as its taxonomy, then use `category` as the `taxonomy` below.

```
// in functions.php
function get_random_gallery_post_by_term( string $term ) {
    // Setup args
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'gallery',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby'        => 'rand',
        'tax_query'      => array(
            // Query post by custom taxonomy term
            array(
                // update your_gallery_taxonomy_name to match your actual taxonomy name
                // You can find taxonomy name on your browser address line when you're on the taxonomy admin page
                'taxonomy'     => 'your_gallery_taxonomy_name', 
                'field'        => 'slug',
                'terms'        => $term
            )
        ),
    );
    // Execute query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // Return found post or false, if not found
    return $query->posts ? $query->posts[0] : false;
}

// in some template file
$gallery_post = get_random_gallery_post_by_term( 'my-gallery-category' );
// Do something with the post
if ( $gallery_post ) {
    // Thumbnail, empty string if thumbnail not found
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $gallery_post->ID, 'thumbnail' );
    // Content
    echo wp_kses_post( $gallery_post->post_content );
}
```